# Передача данных в контроллер из ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь передать в контроллер сериализованную форму и ещё 1 параметр.
Если просто посылать форму тогда всё приходит, вот код:
JS:

```
$('#modalWindow').on('click', '#send', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/LoadImage",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Привет');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadImage(Car car)
        {}
```

Все поля на форме обёрнуты в Html.beginform

А вот если я хочу передать кроме формы ещё 1 параметр, тогда этот другой параметр приходит а вот форма нет, вот код:

JS:

```
$('#modalWindow').on('click', '#send', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/LoadImage",
            data: {
                "car": $('form').serialize(),
                "base64img": $('#autoPicture').attr('src')
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Привет');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadImage(Car car, string base64img)
        {}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему форма не передаётся? И как можно передать одновременно и форму и стринговскую переменную отдельно, не хочется расписывать тут все поля по 1, их не мало.

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо дописать к форме параметры через амперсанты:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'url',
    data : $('#form').serialize() + "&par1=1&par2=2&par3=232"
}
```

Ответ найден [в теме на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398783/jquery-form-serialize-and-other-parameters.) .